# How to create skeleton Loading in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to create "skeleton loading" in Nuxt.js, but I have a problem with the moment when routing to the page. Nuxt.js doesn't change the page until the success of 'fetch' and 'asyncData' by default.
Can I go to the page at once, and then wait for the data and fetch?

On the example:

```vue
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="sceleton-loading">
            <h1> <svg> <!-- h1-empty content animation--> </svg>  </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>{{ val1 }}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
    async asyncData(){
        let val1 = await (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(
            () => resolve('work'), 5000
        )));
        return {
            val1
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a middleware named skeleton :

```
export default function({ store, route }) {
  let skeleton = null;

  if (route.name.indexOf("page-one") !== -1)
    skeleton = "skeleton-page-one";
  else if (route.name.indexOf("page-two") !== -1)
    skeleton = "skeleton-page-two"; 
  ...

  store.commit("UPDATE_SKELETON", skeleton);
}
```

And use it in your pages :

```
middleware: "skeleton",
```

in your layout

```
 <v-app>
    <header/>
    <main v-if="page_loading" class="main">
      <page-one-skeleton v-if="skeleton === 'page-one'" />
      <page-two-skeleton v-if="skeleton === 'page-two'" />
    </main>
    <nuxt v-else />
    <footer/>
    <common />
  </v-app>
  <script>
  computed: {
    skeleton() {
      return this.$store.state.skeleton;
    },
    page_loading() {
      return this.$store.state.page_loading;
    }
  }
  </script>
```

In your store :

```
export const state = () => ({
  skeleton: null,
  page_loading: false

})

export const mutations = {
  UPDATE_SKELETON(state, data) {
    state.skeleton = data;
  },
  UPDATE_LOADING(state, data) {
    state.global_loading = data;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The same problem I was facing, My solution is

- First, create a middleware in /middleware directory
- Register it in nuxt.config.js file like this

```
    router: {
        middleware: 'skelton'
    }
```

In \middleware\skelton.js

```
    export default function ({store}) {
      if (!process.server) {
        store.commit('ui/changeSkletonLoading', {
          skeltonLoading: true
        })
      }
    }
```

Add file in store\ui.js directory

```
    export const state = () => ({
        skeltonLoading: false,
    })

    export const mutations = {
        changeSkletonLoading(state, payload) {
           state.skeltonLoading = payload.skeltonLoading;
        }
    }
```

Now go to your component file and add this code

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <v-skeleton-loader
          class="mx-auto my-2"
          v-if="skeltonLoading"
          type="card-heading, list-item-three-line"
        ></v-skeleton-loader>
        <div v-if="!skeltonLoading">// PUT YOUR CONTENT HERE </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import { mapState } from "vuex";
    export default {
      computed: {
        ...mapState("ui", {
          skeltonLoading: state => state.skeltonLoading
        })
      },
      created() {
        this.$store.commit("ui/changeSkletonLoading", {
          skeltonLoading: false
        });
      }
    };
    </script>
```

Whenever you click to go on another route it will show you Skelton loading.

> Note: It will not show Skelton loading on page load but it will show Skelton loading on page change (route navigation)